# Angularjs Controller is not initialized

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on on angularjs app and we need to integrate with another angularjs app.  On click of a button on first app modal window and its content should get it form app2.  I am trying below approach but app2 controller/module is not getting initialized.  Here is the error

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppTwoCtrl' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Here is the code snippet.

1. AppOneController.js

   ```
   //first module/controller
   define(['main'], function(ng, main) {  // we are using require.js and all controllers are declared in main.js
   angular.module('AppOne', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
   .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //stateprovider code
     $stateProvider.state('landing', {
         url: '/landing',
         templateUrl: '../landing/AppOne.html',
         controller: 'AppOneCtrl'
       });
   }
   controller('AppOneCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'inventorySvc', function($scope, $rootScope, inventorySvc) {
   console.log('in the controller')

   $scope.add =  function () {
           var addVCGUrl = getBaseURL() + "/../../apptwo/landing/AppTwo.html";
               var add_node_Modal = $modal.open({
                   templateUrl: addVCGUrl,
                   size: 'sm',
                   backdrop : 'static',
                   resolve:{
                    //code here
                     },
                     modalTitle: function () {
                     // cod here
                     }
                   }
               });
           };
   }
   ```

   /landing/AppOne.html   => html from the first app

   ```
     <html ng-app="AppOne">
        <div>
           <div ng-click="add()">
              <div class="addVCG">Add</div>  
          </div>
       </div>
    </html>
   ```

   2. AppTwoController.js

// second module/controller

```
define(['main'], function(ng, main) {  // we are using require.js and all controllers are declared in main.js
angular.module('AppTwo', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     //stateprovider code
      $stateProvider.state('landing', {
          url: '/landing',
          templateUrl: '../landing/AppTwo.html',
          controller: 'AppTwoCtrl'
        });
    }
controller('AppTwoCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    console.log('in the controller')
}
```

/landing/AppTwo.html

```
   <!--html from the second app-->
   <html ng-app="AppTwo">
        <div>
           You are in App2 module and apptwo controller
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you have an `ng-app` reference anywhere in your html?

Comment: Yes it is. i forgot to add in the example code.. .I have updated now.

Comment: Both of your modules are missing a closing quote after ngAnimate

Comment: actually to make it simple i took piece of code from my project and edited little bit to shorten. because of that missing qoute.  sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use nest ng-app directives.  From the ng-app docs,
"AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other."
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

I suggest moving AppTwoCtrl to AppOne's module.

If that is not an option, you can use an iframe in your modal to load the AppTwo url.  This will include additional challenges if you're wanting to communicate data back from AppTwo to AppOne though.

Comment: yes, you are right.. I have used iFrame but i get into other issues. we have changed the logic now.